# How to parameterize the range argument of a function using another cell's value

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, say I am trying to find average of 5 cells, I can put a formula

```
=Average(C1:C5)
```

I would like to modify the formula such that

```
= Average(C1:CXXXX)
```

where XXXX comes from another cell.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at the [`INDIRECT` function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) if you need it as a fomula in a cell - you can use it like this, assuming that D1 contains the row that you call XXXX in your question:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C1:C"&D1))
```

If this is in vba, then you can use:

```
= Average(Range(Range("C1"),Range("C") & XXXX))
```

where XXXX is the row number, assuming that Average is a function that you have defined somewhere.

Comment: The INDIRECT function was exactly what I was looking for. I am not familiar with VBA. Will explore it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the INDIRECT function.  Indirect returns the reference by a string.  INDIRECT("A1") returns the cell A1.

Your values are in the C column.  Let's say that the XXXX is in cell D1.  The formula becomes

```
=AVERAGE(C1:INDIRECT("C" & D1)).
```